# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionError: database "mydb" does not exist

Tags: sequelize.js

A db is added to a Node.js 14.17.x project. Here is the db related code in `server.js`:

```
require("./startup/db");

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Here `db.js` is responsible to connect to the db. A skeleton `mydb` (with only one table name without any col or other detail) has been created with pgadmin4:

```
const Sql = require("sequelize");  //<<==ver 6.6.2
const db = new Sql('mydb', 'postgres', `${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}`, {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',  //<<==ver 14
    port:5432,
    
} );
console.log("after db : ", db);  
db.sync({force:true}). //<<==force to generate db
    .then((res) => {
        console.log("db done!");
        console.log(res);  
    }); //create db 

module.exports = db;
```

Here is the error on console output:

```
Listening on port 3001
(node:13418) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionError: database "mydb" does not exist
    at Client._connectionCallback (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:184:24)
    at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
    at Client._handleErrorMessage (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:325:19)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:114:12
    at Parser.parse (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xjc_bbone/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:13418) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13418) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The problem is weird as the same code has been used in other Node.js projects. What is missing here?

Comment: There are version 13 and 14 running on the same server and `mydb` was created under 14. Is it possible that the app is trying to connect to ver 13?

Comment: Problem solved. There are 2 version of Postgres running on the server and port specified in the connection string was pointing to old version.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.